# 'Microsoft.Moles.Framework.MbUnit.MoledAttribute' is not an attribute class

Tags: mbunit, gallio, moles

I'm attempting to use Moles with **Gallio/MbUnit**.  After referencing `Microsoft.Moles.MbUnit`, and including `Microsoft.Moles.Framework.MbUnit`, I added the **[Moles]** attribute to a test I wrote with Moles.  Unfortunately, it is not highlighted blue (as a recognized attribute).  When I attempt to build, I get the following errors:

`Microsoft.Moles.Framework.MbUnit.MoledAttribute` is not an attribute class

The type `MbUnit.Core.Framework.DecoratorPatternAttribute` is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly `MbUnit.Framework, Version=2.4.2.355, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5e72ecd30bc408d5.`

It appears that the MbUnit lib being referenced is **v2**, unfortunately I'm using `Gallio v3.2.3 w/` **MbUnit v3**.  Is there possibly a version difference?  Will there be support for the latest **Gallio/MbUnit**?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

[Mocking the Unmockable: Using Microsoft Moles with Gallio](http://geekswithblogs.net/thomasweller/archive/2010/04/28/mocking-the-unmockable-using-microsoft-moles-with-gallio.aspx)

It's provides exactky what you're looking for: A Moles extension for Gallio/MbUnit v3.

HTH